# Typedef abstract type pointer to concrete type pointer to avoid casting in c programming

Tags: c, interface, casting, typedef

I have a header file containing functions that operate on pointers of abstract data types to hide the dependency in the header. To accommodate multiples platforms, the functions declared in the header have multiple implementations/platforms in separate files in the source tree, each using its own concrete underlying type to implement the interface. Of course, only one of these implementations is linked in the final program, depending on the chosen platform in the build.

foo.h

```
#pragma once
typedef struct foo Foo; // abstract: never defined in the program and used as pointer
Foo* foo_create(void);
void foo_transmogrify(Foo* f);
```

fooImplBar.c

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h" // from a library that defines Bar 

Foo* foo_create(void)
{
    Bar* bar = bar_create();
    return (Foo*) bar; // the cast is needed here to avoid the error
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
     bar_transmogrify((Bar*) f); // another cast here
}
```

fooImplBaz.c

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "baz.h" // from a library that defines Baz

Foo* foo_create(void)
{
    Baz* baz = baz_create();
    return (Foo*) baz; // the cast is needed here to avoid the error
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
     baz_transmogrify((Baz*) f); // another cast here
}
```

*Is there a way to avoid these casts?*

In other words, is there a way to typedef `Bar*` and `Baz*` to `Foo*` in their respective folders? I cannot change the `Bar` and `Baz` definitions with a `Foo` definition in the implementation folders since they (Bar and Baz) come from a library. Thus, here the pattern to forward declare in the header and define in the .c file is not applicable. 
One way to avoid the casts is to use `void*` instead of `Foo*` altogether, at the cost of losing type information, which I find worse than the casts.

Comment: If the types are really all `foo` just for different boards, why not have your `foo_create` function simply associate the correct struct with the `return` based on preprocessor conditionals that identify the board?

Comment: Per C 2018 6.2.5 28, “All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.” This, along with other rules, means that if you create a `Bar` object, convert a pointer to it to a `Foo *`, let some other code have the `Foo *` for a while, then get the `Foo *` back and convert it to a `Bar *`, then you have a pointer to the original `Bar` object and have not violated any C rules or run afoul of undefined behavior due these operations.

Answer (score 0):

## Variant 1

You can try to use a **union**. This will make the interface "foo" dependent on **all** implementations (here: "bar" and "baz"). The advantage is no need to change the implementation.

foo.h

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "baz.h"

typedef union {
    Bar *bar;
    Baz *baz;
} Foo;

Foo foo_create(void);
void foo_transmogrify(Foo f);
```

fooImplBar.c

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo foo_create(void)
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar = bar_create();
    return foo;
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo f)
{
    bar_transmogrify(f.bar);
}
```

fooImplBaz.c

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo foo_create(void)
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.baz = baz_create();
    return foo;
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo f)
{
    baz_transmogrify(f.baz);
}
```

You keep all the type information.

I tried it with a simple project, but `Bar` and `Baz` are incompletely defined in their respective headers. It should also work with complete types.

bar.h

```
typedef struct bar Bar;
Bar* bar_create(void);
void bar_transmogrify(Bar* f);
```

bar.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bar.h"

typedef struct bar {
    int i;
} Bar;

Bar* bar_create(void)
{
    Bar* bar = malloc(sizeof (Bar));
    bar->i = 23;
    return bar;
}

void bar_transmogrify(Bar* f)
{
    printf("Bar: %d\n", f->i);
}
```

baz.h

```
typedef struct baz Baz;
Baz* baz_create(void);
void baz_transmogrify(Baz* f);
```

baz.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "baz.h"

typedef struct baz {
    float f;
} Baz;

Baz* baz_create(void)
{
    Baz* baz = malloc(sizeof (Baz));
    baz->f = 3.14159;
    return baz;
}

void baz_transmogrify(Baz* f)
{
    printf("Baz: %f\n", f->f);
}
```

main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    Foo f;
    f = foo_create();
    foo_transmogrify(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Yes, I know, there is a memory leak if this code is used in some serious scenario. Some `ba[rz]_destroy()` will be needed. But this is just a small issue to be easily solved.

Compiling goes like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c fooImplBar.c -o fooImplBar.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c fooImplBaz.c -o fooImplBaz.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c bar.c -o bar.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c baz.c -o baz.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.o fooImplBar.o bar.o -o mainImplBar
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.o fooImplBaz.o baz.o -o mainImplBaz
```

## Variant 2:

Each implementation completes the incompletely defined structure. You might need to adjust your implementations because it needs to use the same type name.

"foo.h" is identical to yours.

fooImplBar.c

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

Foo* foo_create(void)
{
    Foo* bar = bar_create();
    return bar;
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
    bar_transmogrify(f);
}
```

fooImplBaz.c

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "baz.h"

Foo* foo_create(void)
{
    Foo* baz = baz_create();
    return baz;
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
     baz_transmogrify(f);
}
```

You keep the type information because it is the same type. Each implementation, however, will define the type in its own way.

bar.h

```
typedef struct foo {
    int i;
} Foo;

Foo* bar_create(void);
void bar_transmogrify(Foo* f);
```

bar.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bar.h"

Foo* bar_create(void)
{
    Foo* bar = malloc(sizeof (Foo));
    bar->i = 23;
    return bar;
}

void bar_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
    printf("Bar: %d\n", f->i);
}
```

baz.h

```
typedef struct foo {
    float f;
} Foo;

Foo* baz_create(void);
void baz_transmogrify(Foo* f);
```

baz.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "baz.h"

Foo* baz_create(void)
{
    Foo* baz = malloc(sizeof (Foo));
    baz->f = 3.14159;
    return baz;
}

void baz_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
    printf("Baz: %f\n", f->f);
}
```

main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    Foo* f;
    f = foo_create();
    foo_transmogrify(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling is done like in variant 1.

---

If I understand your introduction correctly the different implementations might be in separate folders. Then you can name the files, types, and functions all the same since you will not use more than one of them in one application.

This is kind of simpler but might not be compatible with your setup.

This is how the example will look like. "foo.h" and "main.c" are identical.

bar/foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "../foo.h"

typedef struct foo {
    int i;
} Foo;

Foo* foo_create(void)
{
    Foo* foo = malloc(sizeof (Foo));
    foo->i = 23;
    return foo;
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
    printf("Bar: %d\n", f->i);
}
```

baz/foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "../foo.h"

typedef struct foo {
    float f;
} Foo;

Foo* foo_create(void)
{
    Foo* foo = malloc(sizeof (Foo));
    foo->f = 3.14159;
    return foo;
}

void foo_transmogrify(Foo* f)
{
    printf("Baz: %f\n", f->f);
}
```

You don't need the wrappers "fooImplBar" and "fooImplBaz" anymore.

Compile:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c bar/foo.c -o bar/foo.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c baz/foo.c -o baz/foo.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.o bar/foo.o -o mainBar
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.o baz/foo.o -o mainBaz
```

Comment: The problem in your solution is that, the interface (foo.h) depends on the concrete implementations, while it should be the implementations that should depend on the interface, as stated in the first sentence of my question.

Comment: Also, it could be argued that there is no memory leak, since the pointers are always in scope and are free'd upon main() exit.

Comment: Well, you sugeested that you can't change the implementations: "I cannot change the Bar and Baz definitions [...]" If you can, see variant 2. Concerning the memory leak, it depends on your real application. For the example you are right but it's not good style.